# How to remove Firefox ESR language packages on Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, firefox

In Debian 11, when I do `apt update` and `upgrade`, if Firefox ESR got an update, it gets for tens (hundreds?) of language packs like `firefox-esr-l10n-hr`. Is there a way to not use these packages? I just want the default Firefox in English.

In Firefox's own settings menu, it doesn't allow me to remove language packages. Any other way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have the `firefox-esr-l10n-all` package installed. It depends on all of the other language packages:

> `$ apt-cache show firefox-esr-l10n-all | grep Depends:`
>
> Depends: firefox-esr-l10n-ach, firefox-esr-l10n-af, firefox-esr-l10n-an, firefox-esr-l10n-ar, firefox-esr-l10n-ast, firefox-esr-l10n-az, firefox-esr-l10n-be, firefox-esr-l10n-bg, firefox-esr-l10n-bn, firefox-esr-l10n-br, firefox-esr-l10n-bs, firefox-esr-l10n-ca, firefox-esr-l10n-ca-valencia, firefox-esr-l10n-cak, firefox-esr-l10n-cs, firefox-esr-l10n-cy, firefox-esr-l10n-da, firefox-esr-l10n-de, firefox-esr-l10n-dsb, firefox-esr-l10n-el, firefox-esr-l10n-en-ca, firefox-esr-l10n-en-gb, firefox-esr-l10n-eo, firefox-esr-l10n-es-ar, firefox-esr-l10n-es-cl, firefox-esr-l10n-es-es, firefox-esr-l10n-es-mx, firefox-esr-l10n-et, firefox-esr-l10n-eu, firefox-esr-l10n-fa, firefox-esr-l10n-ff, firefox-esr-l10n-fi, firefox-esr-l10n-fr, firefox-esr-l10n-fy-nl, firefox-esr-l10n-ga-ie, firefox-esr-l10n-gd, firefox-esr-l10n-gl, firefox-esr-l10n-gn, firefox-esr-l10n-gu-in, firefox-esr-l10n-he, firefox-esr-l10n-hi-in, firefox-esr-l10n-hr, firefox-esr-l10n-hsb, firefox-esr-l10n-hu, firefox-esr-l10n-hy-am, firefox-esr-l10n-ia, firefox-esr-l10n-id, firefox-esr-l10n-is, firefox-esr-l10n-it, firefox-esr-l10n-ja, firefox-esr-l10n-ka, firefox-esr-l10n-kab, firefox-esr-l10n-kk, firefox-esr-l10n-km, firefox-esr-l10n-kn, firefox-esr-l10n-ko, firefox-esr-l10n-lij, firefox-esr-l10n-lt, firefox-esr-l10n-lv, firefox-esr-l10n-mk, firefox-esr-l10n-mr, firefox-esr-l10n-ms, firefox-esr-l10n-my, firefox-esr-l10n-nb-no, firefox-esr-l10n-ne-np, firefox-esr-l10n-nl, firefox-esr-l10n-nn-no, firefox-esr-l10n-oc, firefox-esr-l10n-pa-in, firefox-esr-l10n-pl, firefox-esr-l10n-pt-br, firefox-esr-l10n-pt-pt, firefox-esr-l10n-rm, firefox-esr-l10n-ro, firefox-esr-l10n-ru, firefox-esr-l10n-sco, firefox-esr-l10n-si, firefox-esr-l10n-sk, firefox-esr-l10n-sl, firefox-esr-l10n-son, firefox-esr-l10n-sq, firefox-esr-l10n-sr, firefox-esr-l10n-sv-se, firefox-esr-l10n-szl, firefox-esr-l10n-ta, firefox-esr-l10n-te, firefox-esr-l10n-th, firefox-esr-l10n-tl, firefox-esr-l10n-tr, firefox-esr-l10n-trs, firefox-esr-l10n-uk, firefox-esr-l10n-ur, firefox-esr-l10n-uz, firefox-esr-l10n-vi, firefox-esr-l10n-xh, firefox-esr-l10n-zh-cn, firefox-esr-l10n-zh-tw

Uninstall that, and you will be able to uninstall any of the language packages that you don't want.

Alternatively, uninstall the ones you don't want (or all of them) and that will cause `apt` to offer to remove `firefox-esr-l10n-all` too (as its dependencies will no longer be satisfied).

---

If you no longer have `firefox-esr-l10n-all` installed, the other `-esr-i10n` packages will be marked as automatically installed.  You can remove all packages that were auto-installed when the package that depended upon them is no longer installed by running:

```
apt-get --purge autoremove
```

Alternatively, you can uninstall all of the packages that `firefox-esr-l10n-all` depended upon by running something like:

```
apt-get purge $(apt-cache show firefox-esr-l10n-all |
  sed -n -e '/^Depends:/{s/^Depends: //; s/,//gp}')
```

The `sed` script ignores all lines that don't begin with `Depends:`, removes the `Depends:`  from that line, and deletes all comma characters too.  That gives a useful list of packages for `apt-get purge` to remove.

Comment: Thank you (sorry I can't upvote yet). I just installed Debian 11 with KDE, didn't do any package management other than updates. I get the same results as you in `apt-cache`, but weirdly when I try `sudo apt remove firefox-esr-l10n-all`, it says `Package 'firefox-esr-l10n-all' is not installed, so not removed`. **Edit** looks like I can remove individual languages. So I guess I use that grep output to remove everything. And hope firefox won't try to auto-install them back?

Comment: yep, you can delete all the other language packages.  my guess is that you had the `...-all`  package installed briefly, so maybe try `apt-get --purge autoremove`.  Otherwise try something like `apt-get purge $(apt-cache show firefox-esr-l10n-all | sed -n -e '/^Depends:/{s/^Depends: //; s/,//gp}')`

Comment: OK, I just removed all the language packages. Thanks for the alternatives too :)